# Tangent line to a curve and inertia

Tags: calculus, geometry, soft-question, analytic-geometry

Could one say that a line L is the tangent to curve C at point P just in case :

(1) L is not identical to C [ unnecesssary condition according to the answer given below]

(2) L is the straight line an object would follow in case this object would leave C at P , continuing freely its movement in virtue of inertia

(3) this object would follow the same line L either in case it would come from the left or in case it would come from the right ( in the cartesian plane).

Would this intuitive explanation of " tangent line to a curve" be in agreement with the rigorous definition of the tangent concept?

Note : condition (2) would prevent the X-axis from being the tangent at (0,0) to the curve f(x) = |x| ; on account of conditon (3), it is  f(x) = -x as well as f(x) = x that would not qualify.

Comment: Setting aside the other requirements of tangency for the moment, under what circumstances might a line $L$ be identical to a point $P$?

Comment: David K. - Thanks for pointing out the mistake I made in expressing condition (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, since from a physical point of view you are basically describing the instantaneous velocity. Instantaneous velocity is always tangent to the trajectory of an object:
[image: as you can see here]

About point 1: The tangent line of a point on a differentiable function is the line that goes through that point and has the same slope as that point.
Thus, the tangent of a straight line is the straight line itself.

Comment: Shootforthemoon.- Thanks and congratulations for the high visual quality of this answer!

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames np, also see that L can be C itself

Comment: That's what I understand from the note you added ( about point 1) at the end of your answer. Thanks! ( I thought a line could not be its own tangent).

Comment: Shootforthemoon. - Question edited in order to take this into account.